# How can I override the text for the "Stop Casting" button in the dialog that pops up when I press on the Chromecast icon?

Tags: android

After you're connected to a chromecast, the chromecast icon can then be pressed and a dialog pops up with the option to "Stop Casting". I want to change the text for this button to "Disconnect" but I can't seem to find the location of this string in the code for Google Cast libraries and was wondering if anybody knew how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strongly recommended not to do that since that is what your users see in any other cast-enabled app and being consistent for your users is very valuable. Technically it is doable by re-defining the string resource `mr_controller_stop` in your own string resource file.

Comment: Thanks, decided to leave it unchanged as per your recommendation.

Comment: Thanks, I am glad you decided to do that; maintaining consistency is very important for users. We are aware of the issue you were trying to address.

Comment: BTW is it possible to fix the CC controller so it can be scrolled? On some devices the artwork takes too much space, which makes the 'Stop casting' button hidden